# Script to mv the files with file sequence which is lowest

Tags: shell, unix

Could you help me how to write a shell script

I have the below set of files with
**Folder path:** `abc/xyz`

```
abc122.1001.csv
abc122.1002.csv
abc122.1003.csv
```

I want to search for the abc122.* files in a folder location and move all the files to another location except the file with the lowest sequence number (1001, 1002...)

ex: abc122.1001.csv is the lowest sequence file, all other files with abc122* have to be moved to another location.

I've tried the command below, but it doesn't work

```
find /abc/xyz -name 'abc122*' |sort -r | tail -n1 |  mv {} u05/BACKUP/OLD
```

Comment: I can able to sort the files and take the least sequence file but unable to move them

Answer (score 1):

This can be a starting point:

move_all_but_one.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

shift

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
        mv $@ u05/BACKUP/OLD/
fi
```

Than run it:

```
./move_all_but_one.sh abc122*
```

But still not a final solution as it can crash for very long list of files (argument list too long).

Comment: Nice one. Could be a shell function ?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `{}` is for the exec command of `find`, not for `mv` nor the shell.
Replacing `| mv ...` with

```
| while read f; do mv "$f" u05/BACKUP/OLD; done
```

should help, no ?

the `| sort -r | tail -n 1` could be replaced by `| sort | tail -n +2`

Comment: I see 2 problems with that solution:
1) inefficient - it looks for all files than takes just one (per iteration)
2) not correct - it'll move the last one as well

Comment: @pawel7318 I was just correcting the case I explained. Thanks for pointing about correctness, though.